# Access query using date criteria not working

Tags: ms-access

My (relatively simple, I thought) query to select records based on an End date field doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.  I've attached a screenshot of the query design, and the full SQL is here:

```
SELECT tblHospitals.AdminState, tblContacts.ContactHospital, tblContacts.FullName, tblContacts.EndDate, tblContacts.Qualifications, tblContacts.ContactType
FROM tblContacts LEFT JOIN tblHospitals ON tblContacts.ContactHospital = tblHospitals.HospitalName
WHERE (((tblContacts.EndDate)<#12/31/2017#)
ORDER BY tblHospitals.AdminState, tblContacts.ContactHospital, tblContacts.ContactType DESC;
```

[image]

In researching this issue, I read that date formatting (US vs Australian) can cause date criteria to not work, but I can't see where in the Access settings to check this.  Also, another unresolved date-related question here said they were using MS Access 365, which I'm also using.  Thanks for any suggestions.

PS: here's a sample of what the query returns:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Your code and formatting is correct, and the query _will_ return any record having an _EndDate_ earlier than 2017-12-31. So what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, I mean that the query returns dates later than 31/12/2017 as well; I've added a sample to my original post.

Comment: I would say, that this is not possible, so something else is going on.